# MVC model bind from VUE object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am new to VUE and trying to post a complex object with a list of tokens to an MVC c# route.

The network tab from my post request shows:

```
tokens[0][field]: 129
tokens[0][id]: 1
tokens[0][name]: MyPriority
tokens[0][operator]: 
tokens[1][field]: 
tokens[1][id]: 3
tokens[1][name]: -
tokens[1][operator]: -
```

The MVC controller shows the object, and it shows the number of tokens passed. However, the framework is not binding to the properties being passed in (field, id, name, operator). I am unsure if I need to amend the MVC part to bind, or change the JS object before posting.

the MVC controller is

```
public ActionResult CreateRule(Rule rule, List<Token> tokens)
```

the Js Code is:

```
 methods: {
saveRule() {
  let tokens = [];
  debugger;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.tokens.length; i++) {
    var t = {};
    t.field = this.tokens[i].field;
    t.id = this.tokens[i].id;
    t.name = this.tokens[i].name;
    t.operator = this.tokens[i].operator;
    tokens.push(t);
  }

  let newRule = {
    id: this.rule.id,
    type: this.rule.type,
    name: this.rule.name,
    field: this.rule.field,
    tokens: tokens
  };

  this.$emit("save-rule", newRule);
},
```

It does not feel like a great way to have to copy all the parameters into a new object, so I assume this is not the best way. The vue tutorials had it cloning the data for posting to the server. In any case, it has not made any difference to the MVC reading the post data.

I have seen people try Stringify, but issues around datatypes the { ...rule } seemed to make no difference. I was hoping it was a quick answer as it must be possible, it is far from specialized or unique action!

Comment: I think I need to get the post to be tokens[0].field for it to work? Thoughts? (Have manually hacked the server side code to get the values from Request object, but nice to have model binding working)

Comment: Hi Simon. I am currently trying to send a list of objects in Vuejs to asp.net MVC. I have trouble binding the data as well. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not. I just manually processed it server side getting the values from the request object, and then moved on with life.